# DHTNEW library not working with ATTiny85 + DHT11

Tags: attiny85

I tried to make a simple project with Attiny85 chip and DHT11 sensor. After 2 days of struggle, made it finally work, but not quite as expected. [TinyDHT](https://github.com/adafruit/TinyDHT) library does work, while [DHTNEW](https://github.com/RobTillaart/DHTNew/) does not.

I wonder,

- what can be changed to make any of the libraries work at lower clock rate?
- how to make DHTNew work?

My results so far:

with TinyDHT:

- @ 16 MHz works nominally, showing valid T/H values (if I breathe on the sensor, it shows 95-99% humidity)
- @ 8 MHz, shows nothing (either nan, or zeros)
- @ 1 MHz, shows temp/hum as 5, 5 (or 50, 50, can't tell)

with DHTNEW:

- @ 16 MHz returns SENSOR_NOT_READY
- @ 16 MHz with `mySensor.setDisableIRQ(true);` -> WAITING_FOR_READ at first, then nothing (nan or 0)
- @ 8 MHz WAITING_FOR_READ at first, then TIMEOUT_C
- @ 8 MHz with `setDisableIRQ` -> always TIMEOUT_C
- @ 1 MHz always TIMEOUT_A

Here's the setup on photo and as a scheme. Arduino UNO works as a programmator for Attiny chip, as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Program-an-Attiny85-From-an-Arduino-Uno/). After I upload the code to Attiny85, the chip starts working normally, and there's no need to disconnect the Arduino board. (For actual work, I disconnect it, connect 5V power, and it works the same way.)

Settings in the IDE:

- Board: Attiny25/45/85
- Processor: Attiny85
- Clock: Internal from 1 to 16 MHz
- Programmer: Arduino as ISP

How I test this:

- change clock frequency
- run Tools -> Burn bootloader
- run Sketch -> Upload
- wait till upload ends (RX/TX diodes stop blinking)
- the LED on breadboard blinks me the numbers

[image: Physical look]

[image: Connection scheme]

- [Code for TinyDHT](https://pastebin.com/YdQ3xYER)
- [Code for DHTNEW](https://pastebin.com/q5mEWCan)

Comment: Reading the measurements requires somewhat accurate timings (i.e. `millis()` needs to work). Did you check that a blink sketch blinks at the expected frequency when you change your clock settings?

Comment: @Mat It blinks somewhat correctly, but I need to check that to tell more exactly. It may be some % off, indeed.